# Changing SKU in existing order

Tags: magento

Would anyone be kind enough to explain how to change a SKU in an existing order? We import orders from a 3rd party and the SKUs have spaces in them, which need to be removed. I looked at sales_flat_order_item but not sure how to change. Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to remove blanks in SKUs of order items would be s/t like this:

```
$iIncrementId = '911';
$oOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($iIncrementId, 'increment_id');
foreach ($oOrder->getAllVisibleItems() as $oItem) {
    $oItem
        ->setSku(str_replace(' ', '', $oItem->getSku()))
        ->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean to change the Order number, because SKUs are related to products, not orders.

There's no UI way to change the Order number (there are several extensions but I strongly recommend not using ANY of them) but you can change it yourself if you have access to the database. The table sales_flat_order has an increment_id field where the order numbers are stored. This field is a varchar(50) meaning it supports alphanumeric values.

Magento keeps a UNIQUE index on the field so will not be able to keep duplicates.... unless you are running a Magento version prior to 1.4.x (actually, make that 1.4.0.22). If that's the case, be careful not to duplicate any increment_ids and whenever possible, stick to numerical values to prevent this bug http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=13625

If you don't have access to the DB, you can always create an upgrade script that does the job, but add some logic to avoid duplicates or the installation script will blow in your face and the website will not work until you fix it

Comment: Thanks. Isn't the sku ordered part of the order though?

Comment: The order has a collection of order_items each of which is a snapshot of the product at the moment the order was placed. These order_items have an SKU each, but not the order